# Google Provider Login with Firebase and Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, google-signin

I have been trying to create an Ionic Google login popup with Firebase. However, when the user tries to press the login button, the function is called producing a popup that is surprisingly completely blank.

```
$scope.login = function()
{

        baseRef.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) 
        {

            if (error)
            {
                alert('Hello');
            }

            else 
            {
                $scope.auth = authData.google;
                $scope.user.set("name", $scope.auth.displayName);
                $scope.user.set("image", $scope.auth.profileImageURL)
                $scope.user.save();
            }

        });

};
```

All my permissions in Firebase and Google have been properly set as well as those in the config file. Does anyone have any idea how I can possibly fix this issue to allow a functional popup to spawn?

Comment: popup url? errors in popup?

Comment: The in-app browser opens to a blank page instead of the google login, yes.

Comment: could you open webdeveloper there? or it's just target:_blank?

Comment: The app works entirely fine on my laptop, just not on android.

Comment: then it supposingly is a config policy issue in your index.html?

Answer (score 0):

I had quite a problem with this also.
It appears to work well with iOS, but no luck with android.

By using the command 'ionic state save' followed by 'ionic state restore' ionic readded the android and iOS platforms. It also added cordova-plugin-inappbrowser, cordova-plugin-whitelist (plugins) to the package.json file.

Next, I created an android build using 'ionic package build android' and send it to my OnePlus 2 using TestFairy.

Finally works, for both google and facebook.

In summary once the package.json file included the relevant plugins, I was able to create an APK file that worked with the firebase $authWithOAuthPopup.

(with these amendments, iOS still seems to work fine)